# How to modelling domain model - aggregate root

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design, cqrs, aggregateroot

I'm having some issues to correctly design the domain that I'm working on.

My straightforward use case is the following:
The user (~5000 users) can access to a list of ads (~5 millions)
He can choose to add/remove some of them as favorites.
He can decide to show/hide some of them.

I have a command which will mutate the aggregate state, to set Favorite to TRUE, let's say.

In terms of DDD, how should I design the aggregates?
How design the relationship between a user and his favorite's ads selection?
Considering the large numbers of ads, I cannot duplicate each ad inside a user aggregate root.
Can I design a Ads aggregateRoot containing a user "collection".

And finally, how to handle/perform the readmodels part?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two concepts may help you understand how to model this:

**1. Aggregates are Transaction Boundaries.**

An aggregate is a cluster of associated objects that are considered as a single unit. All parts of the aggregate are loaded and persisted together.

If you have an aggregate that encloses a 1000 entities, then you have to load all of them into memory. So it follows that you should preferably have small aggregates whenever possible.

**2. Aggregates are Distinct Concepts.**

An Aggregate represents a distinct concept in the domain. Behavior associated with more than one Aggregate (like Favoriting, in your case) is usually an aggregate by itself with its own set of attributes, domain objects, and behavior.

---

From your example, `User` is a clear aggregate.

An `Ad` has a distinct concept associated with it in the domain, so it is an aggregate too. There may be other entities that will be embedded within the Ad like `valid_until`, `description`, `is_active`, etc.

The concept of a favoriting an Ad links the `User` and the `Ad` aggregates. Your question seems to be centered around where this linkage should be preserved. Should it be in the `User` aggregate (a list of `Ads`), or should an `Ad` have a collection of `User` objects embedded within it?

While both are possibilities, IMHO, I think `FavoriteAd` is yet another aggregate, which holds references to both the `User` aggregate and the `Ad` aggregate. This way, you don't burden the concepts of `User` or the `Ad` with favoriting behavior.

Those aggregates will also not be required to load this additional data every time they are loaded into memory. For example, if you are loading an `Ad` object to edit its contents, you don't want the favorites collection to be loaded into memory by default.

These aggregate structures don't matter as far as read models are concerned. Aggregates only deal with the **write** side of the domain. You are free to rewire the data any way you want, in multiple forms, on the **read** side. You can have a subscriber just to listen to the `Favorited` event (raised after processing the `Favorite` command) and build a composite data structure containing data from both the `User` and the `Ad` aggregates.

Comment: Also see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401597/many-to-many-relations-in-domain-driven-design/401606#401606

Comment: It helps me move forward but new questions keep coming...but yes ;)

Comment: Please continue asking them here in the same thread if they are related to the topic. Others who visit this Q/A later will have a more complete picture of the problem set.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer given by Subhash Bhushan and I want to add another approach for you to consider.

If you look closely at your question you will see that you've made the assumption that an aggregate can 'see' everything that the user does when they are interacting with the UI. This doesn't need to be so.

Depending on the requirements of the domain you don't need to hold a list of any Ads in the aggregate to favourite them. Here's what I mean:

For this example, it doesn't matter where the the 'favourite' ad command sits. It could be on the user aggregate or a specific aggregate for handling the concept of Favouriting. The command just needs to hold the id of the User and the Ad they are favouriting.

You may need to handle what happens if a user or ad is deleted but that would just be a case of an event process manager listening to the appropriate events and issuing compensating commands.

This way you don't need to load up 5 million ads. That's a job for the read model and UI, not the domain.

Just a thought.